# Implement NSCoding on NSObject

Tags: swift, nsobject, nscoding

I got these errors on NSObject class only.  UIButton and UILabel have no such error.

```
class Foo: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var title = ""
    var children: [Foo] = []



    // MARK: NSCoding
    override public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        super.encode(with: coder)
        coder.encode(title as Any?, forKey: "title")
        coder.encode(children as Any?, forKey: "children")
    }

    required public init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        self.title = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as? String ?? ""
        self.children = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "children") as? [Foo] ?? []
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

[image: NSCoding error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSCoding` (and `Codable` which I think you should be using instead) is a protocol so you are not overriding anything so remove `override` and any calls to `super`

```
public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(title as Any?, forKey: "title")
    coder.encode(children as Any?, forKey: "children")
}

required public init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    self.title = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as? String ?? ""
    self.children = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "children") as? [Foo] ?? []
}
```